# mysqldbcompare fails to ignore database name differences

Tags: mysql, mysqldbcompare

I am trying to use `mysqldbcompare` (version 1.6.5) to automatically generate SQL commands to synchronize the schemas of a development and production database on the same server. I am using the following command:

```
mysqldbcompare --server1=client:3306 \
               --server2=client:3306 \
               dev:test\
               --skip-row-count \
               --skip-data-check \
               --skip-checksum-table \
               --skip-table-options \
               --run-all-tests \
               --changes-for=server1 \
               --difftype=sql
```

The documentation claims that this tool ignores database name differences. However, if there is another difference between two tables, identical foreign key constraints (excepting the database name) are reported in the SQL output. For example, if I clone a database and compare all checks will pass. But if I add a column to a table in the cloned database, I'll see:

```
ALTER TABLE `prod`.`Table`
  DROP FOREIGN KEY Table_ibfk_1,
ADD CONSTRAINT Table_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY(old_column) REFERENCES `dev`.`Table2`(old_column),
  ADD COLUMN new_column int(4) NULL AFTER old_column;
```

Is this a bug, or am I misunderstanding `mysqldbcompare` documentation? It seems like these superfluous foreign key commands should be suppressed. Their presence in the SQL output results in duplicate key errors, making it useless without additional parsing and editing.